# How to keep random generators fixed in python?

Tags: python

I have a code to assign a tag to each node in my network randomly either 'up' or 'down'.

How I can fix this random tags for later on so that they won't change if I run my codes each time?

```
import networkx
import random

def assign_nodes(G):
    state = ['up','down']
    for n in G:
        G.node[n]['sign']=random.choice(state)
if __name__ =='__main__':
    input_data = open("data_test.txt",'r')
    graph = read_graph(input_data)
    assign_nodes(graph)
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use [`random.seed(constant)`](http://docs.python.org/library/random.html?highlight=random#random.seed) to initialize the random number generator to a constant value (replace `constant` with a number of your choice).

Comment: Thanks for your comment. My code keeps error that global name 'constant' is not defined. I assume something is missing?!

Comment: @masti: An actual constant, not the name `constant`! For example, `random.seed(3643781349)`.

Comment: Did you read what I wrote in parentheses? You need to substitute my placeholder `constant` with an actual constant value. `0`, for example.

Comment: Cool! In my case I wrote random.seed('string') before random.choice(state) and it works fine. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can save the graph:

```
from random import random
import networkx as nx

def make_graph():
    G=nx.DiGraph()
    N=10
    #make a random graph
    for i in range(N):
        for j in range(i):
            if 4*random()<1:
                G.add_edge(i,j)

    nx.write_dot(G,"savedgraph.dot")
    return G

try:
    G=nx.read_dot("savedgraph.dot")
except:
    G=make_graph() #This will fail if you don't use the same seed but have created the graph in the past. You could use the Singleton design pattern here.
print G.adj
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment but since my graph is very big and I want to run the program many times, it doesn't make sense.

Comment: It might still make sense. Is reading a graph from disk faster or slower than creating one from scratch each time? This might be worth testing if you're spending a lot of time constructing your graph.